# How to get a content type name out of view programmatically

Tags: views

How to get a content type name out of view/views programmatically?

I have a view `views_of_articles` of (content type article), what I need is which hook I should to use to return the content type for each view.

In my case I want to return (article) from views_of_articles.

Comment: Your question is a bit too general to answer. Could you provide more info about the configuration of your view, and how the content type name you want to get relates to that?

Comment: @Mrweiner I edit my question

Comment: You still need to provide context, like what you're trying do. If you mean to pull the content type from a known pattern of views' machine names, you'd be able to do so from any of the view hook functions.